# Could not install mercury-rails in Rails 3.2 Ruby 1.9.3-p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm trying to install Mercury editor: http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/ in my rails 3.2.1 application.
The problem is, that when the page is loading, and the mercury.js file is in the assets/javascripts it crashes with this message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle

  (in /home/pawelski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bundler/gems/mercury-8cb7ae599c34/vendor/assets/javascripts/mercury/mercury.js.coffee)
```

I was looking for reason, and found that requiring mercury/mercury in mercury.js file is the problem. What is wrong? Is the gem not loading correctly?

I tried with an new clean application and the same happened, I guess that it's something wrong in my rails/ruby environment, but where I should start?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly it is something wrong with my lib to compile js with coffee-script.
I changed it to therubyracer, and it works just fine.

Temporary solution for this problem, untill I don't come with another.